# Is there a way to browse Git commit history as a filesystem?

Tags: git, filesystems

My goal is to be able to read files from Git history using a typical text-editor, and even browse them using a typical file manager.

As far as I know, the only way to browse Git history is to check out different commits, making for a messy workflow if you want to, say, load two different versions of a file in your favorite IDE.

I'm looking to be able to browse Git history with a filestructure something like this:

```
.git_history
├──1f3499
│  ├──some_newer_code.c
│  ├──some_code.c
│  └──README.md
├──4efb9e
│  ├──some_code.c
│  └──README.md
└──6205a7
   └──README.md
```

So, is such a filesystem view of Git possible? As far as I understand, RepoFS and VFSforGit (formerly GVFS) do not do this, but I do not have any experience with these. I'd prefer to do this with "just git" if possible.

I apologize if this has been asked before. I am sure it must have, but I searched quite a bit and could not find it.

Comment: GitFS and RepoFS seem to be the tools that exactly do that. Both are Linux FUSE filesystems.

Comment: If you just want to view some commit(s) and/or files within them in some editor that doesn't know how to invoke a Git command to extract those, consider using `git worktree add` to add detached-HEAD work-trees that have those particular commits checked out.

Comment: Ah! `git worktree add` is a good built-in workaround, while being a bit clunky. On closer look, it appears RepoFS *does* indeed do this. I haven't tried it out yet to confirm

Answer (score 0):

The tool gitk can display as "Tree" mode in lower right of window. It is not a filesystem but can give you an overview what repo file structure of at a certain commit looks like:
[gitk example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBAc5.png)

Git only records file changes of a commit, storing all files in repo for each commit may not be a good idea from disk-usage perspective. Thus using a tool may be a better way to achieve the goal.